# How to change the download preferences of chrome at runtime using selenium c#? For everyfile there will be different download path

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on selenium using c# I want to change the chrome download pref frequently at runtime. How can I achieve this?

Currently, I'm using below code for one time.

```
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"D:\");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("intl.accept_languages", "nl");
chromeOptions.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("user-data-dir=C:/ChromeProfileConfig");
_driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

Comment: So what is the problem in your code?

Comment: If this code is used every time at runtime than a new chrome window will be opened which is not required.

Comment: You don't have to call this everytime. Just call this initially while before launching the Chrome browser only once.

Comment: Yes, but this will set the pref only once. I have to keep changing the pref at runtime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [download and save multiple csv files using selenium and python from popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45097302/download-and-save-multiple-csv-files-using-selenium-and-python-from-popup)

Comment: DebanjanB @ I want to change the download path for every file, I will download.

Comment: It looks similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486121/change-download-location-and-name-for-each-file).

Comment: Will this work for web apps also..